# Why am I getting MySQL error 1064

Tags: mysql

This is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sms_data_updated` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_sms_received` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sender_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sender_number` char(14) NOT NULL,
  `key_word` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `message_content` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `date_received` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_inserted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `categories` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Division` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `location_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And when use the following INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO sms_data_updated (id_sms_received, sender_name, sender_number, key_word, message_content, date_received, Division, location_name) 
VALUES (1,Shahriar Khondokar,+1726740333,,This is message content1. I need help1.,2012-10-16 10:11:09,Barisal,Borishal)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'Khondokar,+8801726740333,,This is message content1. I need help1.,2012-10-16 10:' at line 1
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings like Shahriar Khondoka needs quotes around it. Like this:

```
INSERT INTO sms_data_updated (id_sms_received, sender_name, sender_number, key_word, message_content, date_received, Division, location_name, Latitude, Longitude) 
VALUES (1,'Shahriar Khondokar',rest of columns...)
```

Answer (score 3):

string values must be wrap with single quote

```
VALUES(1,'Shahriar Khondokar','+172674033','This is message content1.',...)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a hanging comma after the `location_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a different number of values as the amount of rows you are inserting into in the query. This could be causing an issue.